# How do I move a dataset from Huggingface to Google Cloud?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, huggingface-datasets

I am trying to use huggingface multi_nli to train a text multi-classification ai in google cloud. I want to call the ai from a firebase web app eventually. But when I try this code in colab:

```
!pip install datasets
from datasets import load_dataset



# Load only train set
dataset = load_dataset(path="multi_nli", split="train")
```

It says its saved in /root/.cache/huggingface/datasets/multi_nli/default/0.0.0/591f72e... but I can't find the file, only a variable version, so I can't move it to google cloud. What is missing for the download to work? Is there some other workaround get it to go to google cloud?

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to do with the method `Dataset.save_to_disk` and the help of the package `gcsfs`. You will need first to install `gcsfs`:

```
pip install gcsfs
```

And then you can use the methods `Dataset.save_to_disk` and `Dataset.load_from_disk` to save and load the dataset from Google Cloud Storage bucket. To save it:

```
from datasets import load_dataset
from gcsfs import GCSFileSystem

fs = GCSFileSystem()

dataset = load_dataset(path="multi_nli", split="train")

dataset.save_to_disk("gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME_HERE/multi_nli/train", fs=fs)
```

This will create a directory in the Google Cloud Storage bucket `BUCKET_NAME_HERE` with the content of the dataset. Then to load it back you only need to execute the following:

```
from datasets import Dataset
from gcsfs import GCSFileSystem

fs = GCSFileSystem()

dataset = Dataset.load_from_disk("gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME_HERE/multi_nli/train", fs=fs)
```

For more information, please refer to:

- [Datasets - Cloud Storage](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/filesystems)
- [gcsfs](https://gcsfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)